# What is the difference between "\__signed" "\__signed__" and "signed"?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am studying `"include/asm-x86/types.h"` and I'm a little confused about the meaning of `\__signed__`.

When I Google this keyword, I cannot get any useful information. Why not just use `signed` instead of `\__signed__`, does it have a special meaning?

Answer (score 1):

That is used for backwards compatibility, when older compilers didn't recognize `signed` keyword, such alternatives were used.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `__signed__` and `signed` is to do with namespaces.  The `signed` names are only available in the `__KERNEL__` and not outside.

As stated at the top of the [header file](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/asm-x86/types.h?v=2.6.25.8) you mention:

```
/*
* __xx is ok: it doesn't pollute the POSIX namespace. Use these in the
* header files exported to user space
*/
```

For the `signed` names without underscores it states this:

```
/*
* These aren't exported outside the kernel to avoid name space clashes
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

`__signed__` is also used for compile with `gcc -traditional`, where the keyword `signed`is not recognized.

Don't google using `c __signed__`, because special characters like `__` are skipped in the search, do a literal search using `c "__signed__"` and you will get useful information.

Comment: thank you for your inform. I have found some useful information about this. http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0610.3/1379.html